# Chern-Simons and framing dependence$.$

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, topological-quantum-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I posted this question to physics.SE last week (cf. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442758/84967)), but it got not attention. I hope it is not too trivial to post it here.

According to ref.1, the correlation functions of a Chern-Simons theory are topological invariants, up to the so-called *framing*, that is, the trivialisation of $TM\oplus TM$. The origin of this framing dependence is the UV divergences, which require a regularisation. The standard choice is to use point-splitting, where links are fattened up.

1. How exactly does framing the link introduce a dependence on the trivialisation of $TM\oplus TM$? What role does this bundle play here?
2. How can an observable possibly depend on a trivialisation? To me, that's like saying that, for example, the temperature of a black hole depends on the system of coordinates you use. Nonsense!

**References.**

1. *Chern-Simons Theory and Topological Strings*, M. Mariño, [arXiv:hep-th/0406005](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406005).

Comment: Can you give a more precise reference in your document? I am surprised that "framing" here means trivializing $TM \oplus TM$ as opposed to $TM$ itself.  Regarding (2), do you also object to the notion of spin structures? Sometimes you need extra structure to pin down an invariant that might otherwise have some discrete ambiguity.

Comment: @MikeMiller 1) See e.g., the last paragraph of the first column on page 3. 2) I am mostly fine with a dependence on a spin stricture (not every CS theory depends on it though). My main objection is not a dependence on any extra structure, but a dependence on a *trivialisation*. To me, it seems that nothing should really depend on a trivialisation.

Comment: But it's the same story: you're using it to pin down an invariant that might have discrete ambiguity. Note that in particular you only care about the homotopy class of trivialization, of which if $E$ is an $n$-dimensional trivializable vector bundle, there are $[M, SO(n)]$ many of these.

Comment: @MikeMiller Hmm that sounds more reasonable. I am not familiar with the notation $[\cdot,\cdot]$ though. What do you mean by it? In any case, thanks!

Comment: Homotopy classes of maps; there are countably many, sometimes finitely many. (This still leaves open precisely what the framing does and how things change when you modify it.)

Comment: I think by "framing" the question means [Atiyah 2-framing](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Atiyah+2-framing).